# Could machine learning be used to select best parameter for more than one loop optimization?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, optimization

I do not know if i can ask this question here or not. But I really need it.

I'm very new to ML/DL/NN field.

I have seen many articles tackling the problem of **selection of the best parameter for loop optimization** like use **ML/DL/NN** to find **best tile size** only or **best unrolling factor** only or best **vectorisation factor** only.

So I wonder if is it possible to create a machine learning model that can at once find best parameter for loop unrolling, tiling and vectorisation **together**.

I got hard to reformulate my question but what I want to say whether is it possible to do a model that can learn for every loop optimization which is the best parameter. Will it require only to create a complexe model. To take more time to train it.

I tried to find an article to find a model in the internet that fix that but did not find yet. I asked this question cause i really have limited knowledge about machine learning.

Thank you to share any useful help or article that may answer my curiosity. Thank you again.

**Honestly I have been afraid that my question will be misunderstood or taken as subjective, or get any pb so I hesitated at first but finally find if i do so will never learn so i get the courage to ask so I will accept every critic.**

Comment: perhaps you're looking for "bayesian hyperparameter optimization"?

Comment: @shimao I'm null in ML and i do not know about bayesian hyperparameter optimization i have to search in the internet to understand it. Thank you very much